# How to fix wrong API request in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, api, cypress

I am trying to create API request for login to chess.com site, but it looks like the request fails. Steps to reproduce:

1. I send the request manually and check it in Google developer tools. Here is the result:

> ```
> Request URL: https://www.chess.com/login_check
> ```

```
  Request Method: POST
  Form Data
  _username: user@test.com
  _password:1234567
  login: 
  _target_path: https://www.chess.com/
  _token: cQr-epETT8R1cTUDY-AFua1cHdE46sHqY3OyDXgDz_k
```

2. I created GET request in Cypress for getting the token and then used this token along with my credentials in my POST request to the server to be logged in. Here is my request:

```js
describe("Login via API", () => {
  it("Send request for the token", () => {
    cy.request("GET", basicLinks.loginUrl).then((response) => {
      const token = Cypress.$(response.body).find("#_token").attr("value");
      cy.request({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/login_check",
        form: true,
        body: {
          _username: "test@yahoo.com",
          _password: "12345",
          login: {
            _target_path: "https://www.chess.com/",
            _token: token,
          },
        },
      });
    });
  });
});
```

3. But it look that there is something wrong with the request because as far as I can see I got the initial login page as the server response. Could anybody advise what I am doing wrong and how can I fix my request? Please find attached screenshot containing the data mentioned above.
   [image]

Comment: Can you print the token value before `cy.request` using `cy.log(token)` to check whether the value is being correctly stored.

Comment: Yes the value of the token is used properly. You can see it in the screenshot above in the request body at the end of the string.